# explanation of Big O on code

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

I need some help understanding Big O concepts on code. We only went over this for 30 mins and we did not discuss how to interpret code on java (I think?). Any who, I'll try to attempt my solution can you guys tell me if I'm right or wrong and give me a proper explanation?

thank you!

```
 sum = 0 ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) --> n
        for ( j = 1 ; j < n^3 ; j = 3*j ) --> n*(3n^3) (WRONG) --> log(n)
            sum++ ;
```

thus the big O on this one is O(n^4) (WRONG)
right answer = O(nlog(n))

```
sum = 0 ;
for ( i = n ; i > 0; i = i/3 ) --> n^(1/3) (WRONG) --> log(n)
    for ( j = 0 ; j < n^3 ; j++ )--> n^(1/3) * (n^3)
       sum++ ;
```

Thus the Big O on this one is O(n)(WRONG)
right answer = O(n^3log(n))

Comment: Multiply outer loop and inner loop: n^(1/3) * n^3 = n^(3 + 1/3)

Comment: think about it logically for a second...if the inner loop is n^3 like you claimed, why would running it n^(1/3) times bring it to O(n)? How can you nest a loop and come out with a lower O() than by just having that loop stand alone?

Comment: Everyone is saying that the complexity of the `j = 3*j` and `i = i/3` loops is O(n^3) or O(n^(1/3)). But this is wrong. In both cases it's O(log n).

Comment: also, your first example isn't O(n^4), it's O(nlog(n)). I'll leave the reason to you as an exercise, just know it has to do with the fact that j grows exponentially in that inner loop.

Comment: okay, so now I'm confused. Since in both cases there is expotential growth. its O(log(n))? So to clarify, q1: n*log(n) because the increase of n^3. And q2: is O(log(n)) because both loops are log(n)?

Comment: The first one increases in value exponentially resulting in only O(log N) steps being required, the other decreases in value exponentially, also resulting in only O(log N) steps being required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first example:

```
sum = 0 ;
for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) --> n
   for ( j = 1 ; j < n^3 ; j = 3*j ) --> O(log n)
        sum++ ;
```

The second loop will  be logn since we keep multiplying j by a factor of 3 each time, So the order will be `O(n logn)` and not n^4

The Big O calculations for each loop is right, however, if you have a loop within a loop, you multiply the calculations.

```
sum = 0 ;
for ( i = n ; i > 0; i = i/3 ) --> log n
    for ( j = 0 ; j < n^3 ; j++ )--> n^3
       sum++ ;
```

The first loop here will also be of log n since you're constantly dividing by 3, So multiplying the order of the 2 loops we get:

```
O(logn * n^3) = O(n^3 logn)
```

We cannot reduce that further since we have no constants to remove.

Just to point out a simple misconception we can have for this case, normally if we have the below scenario, we can reduce it like

```
O(n^3 + n^2) = O(n3)
```

However, your scenario is not an addition of orders, it's multiplication, so again we cannot remove the `O(logn)` here.

**How to analyze code:**

This is how I do it, lets take an example

```
for(i=0; i < n; i++)
    for(j=0; j < n*2; j++)
for(k=0; k<n; k++)
    for(l=0; l<n; l+=3)
        for(m=0; m<n; m*=2)
```

First, find the big 0 for each loop:

```
for(i=0; i < n; i++)        --> O(n)
    for(j=0; j < n*2; j++)  --> 2n = O(n)
for(k=0; k<n; k++)          --> O(n)
    for(l=0; l<n; l+=3)     --> n/3 = O(n)
        for(m=0; m<n; m*=2)  --> O(log n)
```

Multiply the outer loops by their inner loops:

```
for(i=0; i < n; i++)        --> O(n) * O(n) = O(n^2)
    for(j=0; j < n*2; j++)  --> 2n = O(n)
for(k=0; k<n; k++)          --> O(n) * O(n) * (log n) = O(n^2 (log n))
    for(l=0; l<n; l+=3)     --> n/3 = O(n)
        for(m=0; m<n; m*=2)  --> O(log n)
```

Now we add the orders of the outer loops, so we get:

```
O(n^2) + O(n^2 log n) = O(n^2 + n^2 (logn))
```

And then we reduce the order. In this case, n^2 log n has a greater growth rate than n^2, so we can just remove n^2 since the n^2 logn will suffice to explain the growth rate. So finally, we have:

```
O(n^2 (log n))
```

Comment: Oh that was a silly mistake, then the end result will ultimately be O(n^(3+1/3))

Is it possible to tell me how to read this, I'm just doing this intuitively and making assumptions. 

thank you!

Comment: I meant the code in general, but it seems to me there is a disagreement in how this is read?(based on the comments)

Comment: ohh, we'll I usually start at each loop and give the loop an order (O), You can just ignore single statements. After giving each loop an order, start by multiplying the order of all nested loops, then you add all of the orders. I'll update the question to give an example.

Comment: I've updated the answer to give an example of how I read the code to come to the Complexity.

Comment: Holy cow, thank you for giving me time to explain this to me. I really appreciate it

Comment: You're welcomed, please do give back to the community, lots of people need help. Welcome to StackOverflow ;).

Comment: it seems like people here are saying the answer to q1: O(nlog(n)) and q2: O(log(n))?

Comment: Ohh, seems you have edited the question to add the first part, yes it is n logn. Hold, I'll add an explanation to the answer

Comment: Wow!, these people are right, can't believe I missed that, I've updated my answer!

Answer (score 0):

In the first code block, you got the first `for` loop correct, but not the second `for` loop.  In the second for loop `j` is increasing exponentially, i.e. j = 1,3,9,27...
Therefore, the time increases as the logarithm of the end value.  Let's look at an example, based on this line of code

```
for ( j = 1; j < m; j = 3*j )
```

Here's a table of values for m, j, and time

```
m     j        time
1     -         0       // body of loop never executes   
3     1         1       // body of loop executes one time  
9     1,3       2     
27    1,3,9     3  
81    1,3,9,27  4
```

So in this case time is `log_base_3( m )`, in bigO notation that's just O(log m).  If you replace m with n^3, then the time is `3 * log_base_3( n )`, which is actually just O(log n) since bigO ignores constant multipliers.  Bottom line, the solution for the first block is  O( n*log(n) )

The other block can be analyzed in a similar fashion.